# Reshape a list into rows

Tags: text-editing, multiple-cursors

I am looking for an easy way to turn a list such as this:

```
one,
two,
three,
four,
five,
...
```

into something more like this:

```
one,      two,      three,   four,
five,     six,      seven,   eight,
nine,     ten,      eleven,  twelve,
thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen,
```

It seems relatively straight-forward to do "column-major" reshaping by using rectangles, but more often than not it is the "row-major" reshaping that I want, since many programming languages accept a list in this format.

I am a big fan of the [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) package, so I would gladly accept an answer which presents a clever usage of mc features. That is not a requirement though.  I find that multiple-cursors can get a bit laggy after >100 cursors, so there may be better ways to reshape a list when the list is long anyway.

Comment: You could do your column-major reshaping, followed by transposing the table via org-mode commands. Here is an example from Mickey Petersen: http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/fun-vimgolf-4-transpositioning-text-tables

Comment: @deprecated I had a similar idea, but if I have 100 entries which I want to reshape as 25 rows by 4 columns, I would have to first kill and yank 25 rectangles, which seems almost as inconvenient as doing the reshape manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

This solution is derived from the below discussion. The only difference is to not manually insert spaces and use an alternative regex for alignment with does not need spaces and also works with text that has spaces in it.

1. Re-ordering: `M-<` `F3` `C-u M-^` `C-x z z` `C-n` `F4` `M-0 F4`
2. Select whole buffer: `C-x h`
3. Align

   - `C-u M-x align-regexp`
   - **Replace** the content in the minibuffer with `,\(\)` <kbd>RET</kbd>
   - <kbd>RET</kbd>
   - <kbd>RET</kbd>
   - <kbd>y</kbd>

#### Result

```
one,       two,       three,    four,    
five,      six,       seven,    eight,   
nine,      ten,       eleven,   twelve,  
thirteen,  fourteen,  fifteen,  sixteen,
```

### Discussion

1. `M-x beginning-of-buffer`
2. `M-x start-kbd-macro` -- Start recording macro
3. Do below 3 times

   - `C-u M-x join-line` (*I have this bound to `C-j` for my convenience*)
   - Hit <kbd>SPACE</kbd> -- Enter a space character which will later help with alignment. *This is required only in `emacs-elisp-mode`. But even if this space is added regardless, this solution will still work.*
4. `M-x next-line` (`C-n`)
5. `M-x kmacro-end-or-call-macro` -- Stop recording macro
6. `M-0 C-x e` -- Run the macro till the end of buffer is reached. ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7541112/1219634))
7. `M-x mark-whole-buffer` (`C-x h`)
8. `C-u M-x align-regexp` -> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>, <kbd>RET</kbd>, <kbd>RET</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd> -- Do the regex align by Space character for all columns. *Note that if you use `,` instead of <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, you can align content having the space characters too.*

#### Explanation about when it is required to add that extra space in Step 3 above

The function `fixup-whitespace` called in `delete-indentation` function (which `join-line` aliases to) is responsible for adding that space automatically for major-modes not equal to `emacs-lisp-mode`.

The reason is the following line in `fixup-whitespace` function (in `simple.el`):

```
(looking-at "$\\|\\s(\\|\\s'"))`
```

If this expression is true, space is NOT inserted after finishing the join operation.

That  expression is true when any one of these is true:

- if the point is at the end of line
- if the current character is an open parenthesis char as defined in the major-mode's [syntax table](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html)
- if the current character is an **expression prefix** as defined in the major-mode's [syntax table](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html)

And ... `'`, `,` and `#` are counted as expression prefixes in `emacs-lisp-mode`. At the end of joining operation, the point is on the `,` character at the end of the line (e.g.  `one,` or `two,` or `three,`) and so the above `looking-at` expression becomes true when the major mode is `emacs-lisp-mode`; and thus the need to add that extra space manually in Step 3 for this mode.

*Of course you don't have to worry about the space not being auto inserted if alignment is done at comma instead of space character in Step 8.*

Comment: Do I have to `require` an extra package to use `pull-up-line`?  It doesn't seem to exist in my current environment.

Comment: Ah, missed that, it's simply `(defun pull-up-line ()
  "Join the following line onto the current one (analogous to 'C-e', 'C-d')"
  (interactive)
  (join-line -1))`

Comment: @nispio I have replaced `M-x pull-up-line` with `C-u M-x join-line` (same thing).

Comment: Do you need to manually enter that space? Doesn't join-line do that already?

Comment: @Malabarba For me, it concatenates the line below to the current line without any space in-between. `join-line` is alias to `delete-indentation` in `simple.el` and in there the last portion of `delete-indentation` is a call to `(fixup-whitespace)`.

Comment: @kaushalmodi For me, it concatenates the *current line* to the *line above*, with a space in between. This is on `emacs -Q`, version 25.1.

Comment: @Malabarba  For what its worth, I get a space when I use `join-line`, unless I am in the scratch buffer.  Not sure why.

Comment: @nispio Thanks. That might be it. I have tested my solution only in the scratch buffer. I haven't yet edebugged `join-line` for the space inconsistency. Will update my solution on getting a chance to look more into this.

Comment: @nispio @Malabarba It's the `emacs-lisp-mode` in which we need the extra space. I happened to have my scratch buffer in that mode. If I change the major mode to `org-mode` or `fundamental-mode` or even an arbitrary mode like `verilog-mode` (does not come with emacs), I do NOT need to insert that extra space. So YMMV with the major mode. But even if we are adding an extra space, the `align-regexp` step stays the same and always works.

Answer (score 3):

I too love multiple cursors, but for this one I'd use keyboard macros.

```
F3 C-3 C-n M-^ M-^ M-^ C-n C-0 F4
```

Which means:

1. Start kbd macro.
2. Move down 3 lines.
3. Join 3 lines up.
4. Move to next line.
5. Finish and repeat kbd macro indefinitely.

---

You can then proceed to use `align-regexp` like the other answers explain.

Comment: This looks great Malabarba. What command is exactly issued with `F4`? I see `end-kbc-macro`, but you said "Finish and **repeat** kbd macro indefinitely" (which I presume is `F4`).

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina: It is the 0 prefix arg passed to `f4` that means execute the macro repeatedly (forever). As [**the doc**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Keyboard-Macro.html) says, "*An argument of zero repeats the macro
indefinitely, until it gets an error or you type `C-g` (or, on MS-DOS,
`C-<BREAK>`).*"

Answer (score 2):

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `set-fill-column` as desired.
2. <kbd>M-q</kbd>: `fill-paragraph`.
3. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `align-cols`.

The code for `align-cols` is [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/align.el)

Comment: Ingenious! However, `thirteen, fourteen, fifteen,` is longer than `one, two, three, four,` so it won't work for the exact example given.  But hopefully the real use case has words with a more uniform length.

Comment: align-cols is not included with emacs

Comment: whoops, you're right, I'll add the code.

Comment: Instead of `align-cols`, you can use the `align-regexp` from @kaushalmodi's answer: `C-u M-x align-regexp SPC RET RET RET y`.

Comment: @nanny, yeah, `butterfly` would probably work as well.

Comment: @abo-abo I know that's in jest, but it's not as convoluted as it sounds. The extra `RET`s are just to accept the defaults, and the `y` to "repeat [the alignment] throughout line"

Answer (score 1):

- Mark the region
- <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-|</kbd> `column -x` <kbd>RET</kbd>

or `column -x -c N` for lines of (up to) N characters in length.

`column` is a BSD-derived shell command, which you quite likely have if you're on a Unix-like OS.

The `-x` argument gives the "row-major" output that you wanted.

For example, `column -x -c 70` gives you the exact number of rows and columns that you showed in the question:

```
one,        two,        three,      four,
five,       six,        seven,      eight,
nine,       ten,        eleven,     twelve,
thirteen,   fourteen,   fifteen,    sixteen,
```

I don't see a way to specify the minimum spacing between columns, but the main problem with this is that the tab width used by `column` might not match your `tab-width` in Emacs, which might give you some wonky-looking output (even though it's formatted nicely for some other value).

However, once you have the basic arrangement of rows and columns, you can use `align-regexp` to tidy up if necessary:

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `align-regexp`

The pattern would be: `,\(\s-*\)` (i.e. prefix a comma to the default pattern). The next two options are default, and then say "Yes" to "Repeat throughout the line".

n.b. I believe you're going to run into trouble with some of the other answers as soon as your data contains spaces, which is why I think using a tool (`column`) already designed for this task is sensible, and why I recommend using the commas for alignment if you use `align-regexp`, rather than spaces.

Note that when `indent-tabs-mode` is non-nil, `align-regexp` will insert tabs for alignment. You can either `untabify` to convert them to spaces, or use https://stackoverflow.com/a/8129994/324105 to prevent it from happening.